# jsPDF outputs all of the only screen shot the frame instead of printing the entirety of the content

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, jspdf

I have used jsPDF npm module to convert HTML to pdf in my angular application. but I noticed that printing website page to PDF only takes a screenshot of the visible area in Firefox & Chrome and that in Internet Explorer. But I want to convert an entire web page to PDF.

I have done as below:

HTML code:

```
<div id="elemetToPrint">
   <!-- lengthy Code here (which is scrollable and contains graph as well)-->
<button class="printBtn" (click)="downloadPDF()">print</button>
</div>
```

Typescript code as below:

```
const doc = new jsPDF({});
const elementToPrint = document.getElementById('elemetToPrint');
doc.addHTML(elementToPrint, () => {
  doc.autoPrint();
  doc.save('Test.pdf');
});
```

Please do let me know if anyone has a solution.

You can find more reference [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1491)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing the DOM using plain JS in an Angular app. That's not good practice, might as well write a SPA just with JS instead of using a library/framework. jsPDF has a npm package. Now, have you heard of html2canvas

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to html2canvas. This will take a picture of your html and then with jsPDF create a pdf with the picture from html2canvas. This tools goes hand to hand with jsPDF.

https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

**In ANGULAR**

```
 html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
</div>
```

**Tutorial**
http://www.shanegibney.com/shanegibney/angular2-and-jspdf-file-generation/

Comment: Thanks a ton. It was working like a charm. I am trying to capture the contents of my div into a pdf using JSPDF.
Not all the contents of my div are coming into the pdf beyond one page.
The div may contain data for more than one pdf. I tried using page-split option but no success. Please help me. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?